Is there a way in flutter to have nested ListViews without using shrinkWrap or specified height for the sublist?
I need to have a list of elements. Each element will have a list (for example, parent comment and its list of replies). But in this case I need to provide shrinkWrap: true or to provide Container with fixed height for that of list of replies. In my case I cannot have fixed height and I would like to avoid shrinkWrap: true because of performance issues.

you can use slivers and NestedScrollView widget.

@MunsifAli Can you be a bit more specific? I've already tried to do that but it is not working. Maybe there is a misunderstanding. I am already using CustomScrollView inside which there is SliverList, but each item in SliverList needs to have its own SliverList (in this case ListView because sliverList takes render box elements as items). But I cannot avoid putting shrinkWrap: true in that ListView.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

maybe this sample helps you:
class ExpandedListView extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<dynamic> items;
  final Widget Function(BuildContext, int, dynamic) itemBuilder;

  ExpandedListView({
    Key? key,
    required this.items,
    required this.itemBuilder,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: items.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        final item = items[index];
        return Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            itemBuilder(context, index, item),
            if (item is Iterable)
              ExpandedListView(
                items: item.toList(),
                itemBuilder: itemBuilder,
              ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

// you can use ExpandedListView istead of listview
ExpandedListView(
  items: [
    'Parent 1',
    ['Reply 1', 'Reply 2'],
    'Parent 2',
    ['Reply 3', 'Reply 4', 'Reply 5'],
  ],
  itemBuilder: (context, index, item) {
    if (item is String) {
      return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Text(item),
      );
    } else {
      return ExpandedListView(
        items: item,
        itemBuilder: (context, childIndex, childItem) {
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
            child: Text(childItem),
          );
        },
      );
    }
  },
);


Thanks for trying but even that inner ListView.builders needs shrinkWrap:true in order to build those lists.
